# My printer retains some memories from previous jobs' settings

Tags: printing, cups

At home, I'm the only one using Linux; everybody else is on Windows 10. We are using a Canon Pixma MX515 printer connected to our LAN.

Recently, I noticed a strange behavior. After someone else (from his Windows) printed something on photo paper, every print job sent from my Linux computer was printed with 600dpi, instead of the normal 300dpi, which leads to a much longer time for printing text only, as the printer pauses printing regularly to let the ink dry.

Since I printed an empty MS Word document from a Windows computer on our network, jobs from my computer are printed in 300dpi again.

It seems to me that the printer keeps using one "printing profile", or whatever this is called, as long as another is sent to it. However, CUPS or the driver, seem to assume that when printing using the default settings, it's not necessary to send additional information.

But I may be completely wrong, I have no idea how CUPS works under the hood. Any ideas how to fix this behavior?

`/etc/cups/printers.conf`:

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.7.2
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<DefaultPrinter MX515>
UUID urn:uuid:9bd5a6c2-e915-3fd1-4f28-0fc8228b2b1f
AuthInfoRequired none
Info Canon PIXMA MX515
Location Basement
DeviceURI dnssd://Canon%20MX510%20series._ipp._tcp.local/
PPDTimeStamp *
State Idle
StateTime 1451320681
Type 36892
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
ColorManaged Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
Attribute marker-colors \#39D2E7#D945DD#DFD31D,#101010
Attribute marker-levels 100,100
Attribute marker-low-levels 15,15
Attribute marker-high-levels 100,100
Attribute marker-names Color,Black
Attribute marker-types inkCartridge,inkCartridge
Attribute marker-change-time 1451320470
</Printer>
```

Please let me know if you need additional information.

---

OS: Linux Mint 17.3

Comment: I have a Canon Pixma 3250 or 3520. I curse the evil Canon Committee that thought 4 LEDs and 5 pushbuttons constitute a usable interface for something as complicated as a printer/copier/scanner that hooks up to wireless networks. We have Windows, Mac and Linux. Nothing works consistently.

Comment: Are you using the Canon drivers? I have an MG7150 and my deviceURI starts with cnijbe:// so I have the impression you're using a different driver. Search for `cnijfilter` or `IJ Printer Driver`. I usually prefer to use open drivers, but for such printers everything works best when using the manufacturer's drivers, and at least Canon does support Linux (I installed Canon's .dpkg packages).

Comment: I've used Gutenprint drivers so far... I'll see whether I can get the cnijifilter driver to work... I guess I have to dismantle the debian package and fix some outdated dependency, and hope it still works.

Comment: I remeber now... I used the cnijfilter drivers once, but ditched them, as they didn't work; the driver always set the job to "held", and the message `cannot specify model number` keeps popping up in CUPS' error log.